# how to retrieve data from a table in postgresql db to display report based on year where year is in character type

Tags: php, report, postgresql-9.3

I have a PostgreSQL DB table where date1 is the column with character data type. Now I want to retrieve data from a date1 column based on year (2017, 2018) in PHP to generate a report.

table: vnm_entry_data,
column: dept, district, year, count.
db: postgresql

If any questions for clarity, please free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried

Comment: select dept, district,count(*) as count, SUM(CAST(plantaion_count AS float)) as no_plants, substring(date1, '2017') as year from vnm_entry_data where plantation_count!='' group by dept, district, date1;   --- is my query to retrive 2017 data but i am getting 2018 data also saying it null in year column.